# How to obtain my App id (or a POC id)?

Tags: javascript, android, cloud

I was reading the Getting started page on github : https://github.com/weemo/Weemo.js/blob/master/docs/start.md and testing out the sample Android application. I have noticed that I need to enter an AppId in order to login. however , I have no idea how I can obtain a App Id. I read from the provious github page that says:

> When you begin developing your app, you will be granted a "POC" AppID for developing your proof-of-concept app or website. When using a POC-mode AppID, the UIDs used in your app are not validated against an authority. This makes it possible to test your app with "made-up" UIDs and Display Names.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out POC is not used any more. The AppId will be sent to you Via email. Note that in the Android SDK-Helper you have to fill in the App token in the userId section in order to log in. Hopefully this will benefit other people with the same confusion in the future!